# Java task distribution and collection on a grid

Tags: java, concurrency, grid, cluster-computing

I have an application **running on a cluster/grid** where I need to **run N tasks that do not have to communicate**. I only need to **collect the result of each task**. So I have a Master distributing the tasks to some Slaves (possibly running on different hosts) and combining all the results at the end.

As the cluster is controlled by a batch system the configuration of my nodes changes for each run and I get a list of nodes that have been assigned to me for my job.

I'm looking for a library (pure Java) to help me with this. I looked at the following:

**MPJ** - doesn't work for me because of the way that MPJ runs when there are multiple processors available on the same machine. It uses custom class loaders and this gives me problems with a native library that I'm loading (it's loaded multiple times because the custom class loaders load the class multiple times).

**Hazelcast** - works in principle but it's not really made for this (I can distribute jobs with a queue and put the results back in another queue but it seems like a bit of an overkill). What I like is that it's easy to set up the group of nodes (in principle just one needs to be specified and the other nodes can just connect to it).

**Simon/RMI** - I guess I could let each slave register with the master and then let the master distribute jobs to each slave. Or let each slave request a queue where the jobs are queued and a queue where the results should be stored from the master.

**Cajo** - would in principle work but I don't want to have multicast on the grid network and there seems to be no way around this for Cajo.

**RabbitMQ** - I don't like to have an extra server running and it's not pure Java. Same for **ZeroMQ**.

**Akka** - Seems to be overkill as well. And a lot of configuration to set up the group of nodes.

**Hadoop** - Like Akka seems to be an overkill, especially the configuration to set up the group of nodes.

**JPPF** - Seems to be more suited for setting up a long running cluster of servers and nodes. After my application finishes I need to stop all servers and nodes. Also it seems to rely on Serialization of the Tasks which is not an option for me (see further below)

So I would stick with either Hazelcast or Simon. Which one is better suited for this kind of application? Does anyone know another library (not too heavy, not too much configuration). Any other suggestions?

Hazelcasts ExecutorService is not an option btw. because I'm using some JNI and so the serialization would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I finally settled with MPJ. The problem with custom class loaders can simply be circumvented by not using the scripts included in MPJ but instead calling the java program directly with the following parameters:

java class rank mpj-config niodev [additional arguments for the application]

The rank, mpj-config and niodev arguments will be removed by the MPI_Init call.
mpj-config is a file listing number of ranks, a switching threshold for the message protocol and a list of hosts with corresponding port number and rank. niodev specifies the communication mechanism (see MPJ-Express documentation for more details). The config file could look like this:

```
3
131072
a6444@20000@0
a6444@20002@1
a6413@20000@2
```

It is important to seperate the port numbers on the same host by 2, because MPJ uses the specified port + the next one (so e.g. 20000 and 20001).

Simon and Hazelcast were also good solutions but they were a little bit slower than MPJ. Especially the initialization for both is quite a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this solution doesn't work.
Hazelcast provides a multi node task execution with Executor Service.

So you'll get the list of nodes that you want a task to be executed.

And then

```
HazelcastInstance h = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
Set<Member> members = h.getCluster().getMembers();//or any subset given your requirement 
MultiTask<Long> multitask = new MultiTask<Long>(new MyCallableTask("default"), members);
ExecutorService es = h1.getExecutorService();
es.execute(multitask);
Collection<Long> results = multitask.get();
```

The only thing you need to do is to have the class of `MyCallableTask` in the classpath of all nodes.

Comment: Thanks for this but as stated above "Hazelcasts ExecutorService is not an option btw. because I'm using some JNI and so the serialization would be a pain.". Anyway, I would assume that this would also be slower than MPJ as Hazelcast will use it's distributed structures internally to distribute the tasks.